# Why doesn't the recursive function call not change the execution flow?

Tags: perl

```
sub dir_list1
{
    $path=$_[0];
    while(<$path/*>){
        if (-f "$_"){
            print "$path/$_\n";
        }
        else {
            print "dir: $path/$_\n";# if ($entry ne "." && $entry ne "..");
            dir_list1($_);
        }
    }
}
dir_list1(".");
```

When i execute the above code, it first prints ALL the contents of the current directory and then goes on to list the contents of the subdirectory. Should it not go into the sub-dir once it encounters a sub-dir, list the files inside and resume with the parent folder?

Thanks.

[Edit, in response to OrangeDog]

I'm using this code on windows. The output is something like this:
a.txt
b.txt
dir: ./images
c.txt
d.txt
...
[and then the images folder is listed]
./images/qwe.jpg
./images/asd.jpg
./images/zxc.jpg
...

Comment: How do you know your file system isn't just returning the directories at the end of the list?

Comment: @David: I'll look into how functions work in Perl. I guess that's where i went wrong. Can you please post a corrected version of this code for me to look at?

Comment: This has nothing to do with functions, just globals.

Comment: Read David's comment, and imprint it in your brain, unless you are writing a quick dirty '2 am' script, using `strict` and `warnings` (and `diagnostics` optionally) is absolutely compulsory! :)

Comment: I'd say that applies even for a quick and dirty 2am script :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got a bunch of problems here.  Here's a version that actually works:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub dir_list1
{
    my $path = $_[0];
    for (<$path/*>) {
        if (-f $_) {
            print "$_\n";
        }
        else {
            print "enter dir: $_\n";
            dir_list1($_);
            print "leave dir: $_\n";
        }
    }
}
dir_list1(".");
```

Things wrong with the original code:

- Lack of `use strict; use warnings;`
- Not using a lexical variable for `$path`
- Using quotes around a variable is usually redundant (`"$_"`)
- The filenames returned by the glob operator include the path you gave to it

But the fundamental problem was that the glob operator in scalar context can't be used recursively.  The iterator it uses is tied to that particular line of code.  When you recurse, the iterator is still returning filenames from the parent directory.

I changed your `while` (scalar context) to a `for` (list context).  A `for` loop generates the complete list of filenames and then iterates over it, and it can be used recursively.

I'm assuming you're doing this as a learning exercise.  Otherwise, you ought to be using one of the many modules for finding files.  Here's a partial list:

- [File::Find](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aFind) - the classic, a core module since 5.000.  But an annoying interface.
- [File::Find::Rule](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aFind%3a%3aRule) - wraps File::Find in a nicer interface
- [File::Next](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aNext) - has an iterator-based interface that avoids having to read the entire directory tree before returning anything
- [Path::Class::Iterator](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Path%3a%3aClass%3a%3aIterator) - like File::Next, but with the magic filename objects of [Path::Class](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Path%3a%3aClass)

I'm sure there's more I've overlooked.

Answer (score 1):

(I wasn't going to post this as an answer, but you asked for a corrected version of the code in a comment so… my 'correction' would be a wholesale rewrite as part of a philosophy of avoiding wheel reinvention).

I'd handle this using CPAN modules where possible. This has nice side effects such as Doing The Right Thing with path separators on different platforms and cutting the number of lines in the sub routine by 1/3rd.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;  # If you aren't using Perl 5.10 or newer, you should be. say alone makes tidier code
use Path::Class::Iterator; 

sub dir_list1 {
        my $path = shift;
        my $it = Path::Class::Iterator->new(root => $path,breadth_first => 0);
        until ($it->done) {
                my $f = $it->next;
                print 'dir: ' if $f->isa('Path::Class::Dir');
                say $f;
        }
}

dir_list1 "./";
```