# perl :path construction

Tags: perl, path

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
$n1=$ARGV[0];
$n1 =~ s/\\/\//g; 
$dir=$n1;

$n1=&listing;

sub listing{
    opendir(DIR, $dir) or die $!;
    while (my $file = readdir(DIR)) {

        # A file test to check that it is a directory
        # Use -f to test for a file

        next unless (-d "$dir/$file");
        if($file =~ m/^[a-zA-Z]/) {
            @dir_list=$file;
        }
        foreach $va( @dir_list){
            #print $va."NEW DIR \n";
            @md_dir=$va;
        }
        add_path(@md_dir);
    }
    closedir(DIR);
}

sub add_path(@md_dir) {
    foreach $vm(@md_dir) {
        $p=$n1."/$vm";
    }
    @mydir=$p;
    add_infor(@mydir);
}

sub add_infor(@mydir) {
    foreach $myfil(@mydir) {
        print $myfil;
        print "\n";
        opendir(DIR,$myfil)||die("cannot open");
    }
}
```

is my code.... where i am passing the path in command line.... i am getting list of directories.....i am appending to orignal path to open the list directories..
but error is

```
Use of uninitialized value in print at 1.pl line 47.

Use of uninitialized value in opendir at 1.pl line 49.
cannot open at 1.pl line 49.
```

Comment: What are lines 47 & 49 ? What are you trying to do ? Use strict; use warnings; ...

Answer (score 3):

Note:

```
sub add_path(@md_dir) {
    foreach $vm(@md_dir) {
        $p=$n1."/$vm";
    }
    @mydir=$p;
    add_infor(@mydir);
}
```

That is not how functions receive parameters in Perl. The parameters with which the function was called are in the `@_` array.

The purpose of this function is not very clear.

You also seem to assign use `@array = $scalar` liberally. And, while that will not generate any errors (and might be the right thing to do in some cases), what I think you really want is `push @array, $scalar`.

The following should be able to provide you with a starting point:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings; use strict;
use File::Spec::Functions qw( catfile );

my ($top) = @ARGV;
$top = '.' unless defined $top;

listing( $top );

sub listing {
    my ($dir) = @_;

    opendir my $dir_h, $dir
        or die "Cannot open '$dir': $!";

    my @md_dir;

    while ( defined(my $entry = readdir $dir_h) ) {
        next if $entry =~ /^[.][.]?\z/;

        my $path = catfile $dir, $entry;
        next unless -d $path;

        push @md_dir, $path if $entry =~ /^[a-zA-Z]/;
    }

    closedir $dir_h;

    print "$_\n" for @md_dir;
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure what is going on here, as your code is less than entirely readable.

- Do [`use strict;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html)
- Do [`use warnings;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html)
- Do use variable and subroutine names that are readable words instead of littering your code with abbreviations

I suspect one of your major problems is attempting to reuse the same file handle (`DIR`) over and over (including reopening it for a new directory before you've finished with it for a previous one).

Use lexically scoped file handles instead.

Better yet, forget about using `opendir` for this, just go with a CPAN module such as [Path::Class](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Path::Class) (as per [my answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488506/why-doesnt-the-recursive-function-call-not-change-the-execution-flow/4488666#4488666)).

Comment: Show us the updated code (and note that the bullet points are things that will make it easier to find problems with your code and not solutions. The real solution is the last sentence, which calls for a wholesale rewrite, making it unlikely that you'd have the same errors)

Comment: if i remove the last open statement... i am able to get the folder path